# How to calculate the angle between two vectors?

Tags: java, math, vector, trigonometry

We are trying to get the cos value between v and u but we are getting results much higher than 1 or lesser than 0

Where :

```
vx = in.nextInt(); // x speed of your pod
vy = in.nextInt(); // y speed of your pod

int ux = nextCheckPointIdX - x;
int uy = nextCheckPointIdY - y;
```

Here is the formula :

```
double cos = (vx*ux + vy*uy) / ( Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vx, 2) + Math.pow(vy, 2)) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ux, 2) + Math.pow(uy, 2)) );
```

Do you find any errors in the previous line ?

Comment: The dot product of two vectors is the cosine of the angle between times the *product* of their lengths

Comment: @harold I edited the question, we don't want the product

Comment: You do want the product. Like I said, the dot product of two vectors is `cos(angle) * |A| * |B|`, so in order to extract the `cos(angle)` part you have to divide by the product of the lengths. There is no sum of lengths anywhere in this formula, actually that is rare in general.

Comment: You are getting cos(theta). To get theta value, you have to find the arccosine(value).

Comment: @AayushKumarSingha the problem is that his calculated value of cosine is outside the range of cosine.

Comment: Are you allowed to use [`javax.vecmath`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/j3dapi/javax/vecmath/Vector2d.html)?

Comment: @harold I am very sorry that we've had a misunderstanding. Our formula is meant to give cos(angle) = (dot product of u and v) divided by (||u|| . ||v||), however, in order to find (||u|| . ||v||), we've written ( Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vx, 2) + Math.pow(vy, 2)) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ux, 2) + Math.pow(uy, 2)) )

Comment: @bradimus That's it ! We aren't allowed

Comment: @bradimus I have found a mistake in the denominator. Check my answer. Hope it solves the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The denominator was having the problem.

```
int num = (vx*ux + vy*uy);
double den = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vx, 2) + Math.pow(vy, 2)) * (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ux, 2) + Math.pow(uy, 2))) );
double cos =  num / den;
System.out.println(cos);
System.out.println(Math.acos(cos));
```

Comment: @AayushKumarSingha Oh god that mistake. Problem solved ! Thank you.